# Browser extension: eval() user input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, eval, sandbox, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is there a workaround to using `eval()` (on user input) in both Chrome extensions and Firefox WebExtensions?

#### Background:

I'm currently writing a browser extension for both Chrome and Firefox.  An important part of it is that the user can specify certain filters. What I could easily do is:
Let the user enter a RegEx string into a text box and run that over what I want to filter, but not everyone knows RegEx very well and some things would simply not be possible.

To simplify things, let's imagine we're looping over a couple of folders that have a few files in them and we want to pick out the interesting files using a filter. This could look something like that:

```js
filter() {
    let interestingFiles = []
    folders.forEach( folder => {
        let files = folder.files
        files.forEach( file => {
            if (file.name.includes('important')) {
                interestingFiles.push(file)
            } else if (file.sizeMB > 500) {
                interestingFiles.push(file)                
            } else if (file.sizeMB > folder.getBiggest()/100*15) {
                interestingFiles.push(file)
            }
        })
    })
    return interestingFiles
}
```

I'd like to allow the user of my extension to specify a filter like that. The obvious way of doing this would be to provide the user with a textbox, let him/her enter the code and then run `eval()` on that user input.
But, browser extensions refuse to run `eval()` because of security concerns.
Now, my question is if there is a workaround? I mean I don't really want to write my own JavaScript parser for this or even use an existing one. If I could simply create an isolated scope in which `eval()` could be executed safely that would be great.

By the way, the execution of that filter would not happen in a content script, it would happen in a browser action popup, so it has access to the background API.

---

### Things that I tried that didn't work

- Using `eval()` directly:

```
    Error: call to eval() blocked by CSP
    Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src moz-extension://57f1d9cf-71b6-4d64-9b8e-6c5b90ad7341”).
```

- `Components.utils.Sandbox` and `Components.utils.evalInSandbox`:

```js
    var mySandbox = new Components.utils.Sandbox("about:newtab");
    var result = Components.utils.evalInSandbox("string to eval", mySandbox);
```

I can't seem to be able to use them and they seem to be deprecated anyways:

```
    TypeError: Components.utils is undefined [Learn More]
    The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.
```

- I also tried using an iframe and execute `eval()` within that

```js
    document.body.innerHTML = '<html><head></head><body><iframe id="myIframe" src="about:blank"></iframe></body></html>'
    document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.eval('var aa = 1;')
```

But that just results in CSP errors:

```
    12:19:26.787 Error: call to eval() blocked by CSP
    12:19:26.789 Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src moz-extension://f0155032-64bd-40c5-8b09-3bd7a92dc90e”).
```

- And the sandboxing example provided on Google's page [Using eval in Chrome Extensions. Safely.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval) doesn't work for me either. At least it didn't work in Firefox:

```
    about:blank : Unable to run script because scripts are blocked internally.  (unknown)
    Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  samples
    about:blank : Unable to run script because scripts are blocked internally. (unknown)
    The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.  eventpage.html
    Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“script-src moz-extension://6b9a242e-f1db-4efd-a4cc-85d0d5beb79c”).  sandbox.html:17
    Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.  newtab
    about:blank : Unable to run script because scripts are blocked internally.  (unknown)
```

I also couldn't find any mentions of the "sandbox" property for the manifest on Mozilla's MDN sites.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in Firefox.

Comment: You can create a feature request at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: Wait, you think your users don't know regex but they can write javascript?

Comment: @Bergi It doesn't even matter. Regex couldn't solve this anyways.

Comment: @Forivin, Your argument to use JavaScript instead of regular expressions (RE) because people don't know REs is flawed. The concept of REs and their *general* syntax is a concept that exists across many computing environments. The similarities between RE implementations are *much* closer than the similarities between different computer languages. The number of people that will work out how to write a RegEx RE (particularly if you point them at a site that lets them interactively try RegEx) is significantly higher than those that know JavaScript.

Comment: @Makyen First of all, I'm pretty sure I know my target group better than you do and secondly, if you really want to discuss this let's continue the discussion in the chat.

Comment: Is `script-src: "unsafe-eval"` in manifest.json CSP an option?